# How to get accurate match using Flann based matcher?If no match found then it should give the output as No Match Found

Tags: c++

1. How to get accurate match using Flann based matcher?
2. If no match found then it should give the output as "No Match Found".
3. Also can it show the accuracy percentage.

Below is the piece of code where matching is being done:

```
// Match 
  vector<vector<DMatch> > knnMatches;
    Mat testDesc;
    int knn = 1;
    vector<int> bestMatches;
    FeatureDetector *detector = new SurfFeatureDetector();
    DescriptorExtractor *extractor = new SurfDescriptorExtractor();
    DescriptorMatcher *matcher = new FlannBasedMatcher();  // ANN

        trainDesc.push_back(desc);    
        trainImgs.push_back(img_name);
        int temp = 0;
        bestMatches.push_back(temp);        

      matcher->knnMatch(testDesc, knnMatches, knn);

      // Filter results
      for (vector<vector<DMatch> >::const_iterator it = knnMatches.begin();
           it != knnMatches.end(); ++it) {
        for (vector<DMatch>::const_iterator it2 = it->begin(); it2 != it->end();
             ++it2) {
          ++bestMatches[(*it2).imgIdx];
        }
      }

      // Find best match
      int bestScore = 0;
      int bestIdx = -1;
      for (int i = 0; i < bestMatches.size(); ++i) {
        if (bestMatches[i] >= bestScore) {
          bestScore = bestMatches[i];
          cout << "best Score inside if  is:" << bestScore << endl;
           cout << "best Matches inside if  is:" << bestMatches[i] << endl;
          bestIdx = i;
        }
      }

      if (debug > 0)
        cout << "Best match: " << trainImgs[bestIdx] << " Score: " << bestScore
             << "bestidx: " << bestIdx << endl;
      cout << trainImgs[bestIdx] << endl;
```

Comment: Please use markup (e.g. backticks) to mark your code as code and make it easier to read.

Comment: Please show us an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also please specify what you mean by "accurate"?

Comment: I am using PickleDB to store the Images(jpg & pb files). I pass an image(jpg) file and it uses SURF to extract & detect features & Flann to do the matching. When Image is not trained it returns any random image.

Comment: I have modified Sirius Code to perform Image recognition  only. When I search for any untrained data like Gateway of India it gives the answer as Empire state building(which is present in landmarks.pickle file.

Below is code and I SURf & Flann Matching is done in detect.cpp.
https://github.com/saidimu/sirius/tree/master/sirius-application/image-matching

Comment: Content of landmarks.pickle is:--
{"aya-sofya.jpg": ["aya", "sofya"], "brandenburg-gate.jpg": ["brandenburg", "gate"], "White-House.jpg": ["White", "House"], "empire-state-building.jpg": ["empire", "state", "building"], "roman-colosseum.jpg": ["roman", "colosseum"], "golden-gate.jpg": ["golden", "gate"],  "eiffel-tower.jpg": ["eiffel", "tower"], "pyramids-egypt.jpg": ["pyramids", "egypt"], "great-wall-of-china.jpg": ["great", "wall", "of", "china"], "statue-of-liberty.jpg": ["statue", "of", "liberty"]}